# Hagamos [list] sinónimo de [lista]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Observo que ahora mismo [lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista) tiene 239 preguntas y [list](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) tiene 67 (y [seis usan ambas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista+list)).

Mirando un poco cómo se usan, parece que es indistintamente. Por tanto, ¿no os parece de recibo que se unan y den lugar a una única, en castellano, llamada [lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista)?

Comment: Totalmente. No tiene sentido tener esas dos etiquetas independientes

Comment: Es algo que no creo que necesite mucho debate y sin votos negativos o comentarios, lo he hecho. Ahora solo existe [tag:lista] y las preguntas con [tag:list] han sido modificadas.

Comment: @lois6b ¡muchísimas gracias!